# ¿como mostrar el usuario logueado en ASP.NET-MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como puedo mostrar el usuario que se logueó en mi aplicación?, estoy usando **ASP.NET y MVC5**.

Espero y me puedan ayudar con lo que necesito, les dejo mi código del controlador, solo tengo un usuario que es **admin** pero se van agregar mas usuarios, y este dato viene desde la base de datos.

Este es mi **controlador**:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login(string message = "")
        {
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Acceso(string usuario, string contrasena)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contrasena))
            {
                SesionLogin datosUsuario = new SesionLogin();

                datosUsuario = await ObtenerUsuario(usuario, contrasena);

                if (datosUsuario != null)
                {
                    if (datosUsuario.UsuarioLogin != null)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(datosUsuario.UsuarioLogin, true);
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Recetas");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos" });
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos" });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Ingresa usuario y/o contraseña" });
            }

        }

        //[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login");

        }
```

Comment: Donde quieres mostrar el usuario Logueado??? y cuál es la estructura de SesionLogin???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, tienes algo programado en la Vista **Login.cshtml**?, indícalo en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Como veo que no actualizas tu pregunta, te aconsejo leas este artículo donde podrás ver cómo realizar un Login en ASP.NET MVC exáctamente igual al que necesitas:  [Autenticación de usuarios en ASP.NET MVC - Problemas con web hosting en clúster y balanceo de carga](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/4/15/autenticaci%C3%B3n-de-usuarios-en-aspnet-mvc-problemas-con-web-hosting-en-cl%C3%BAster-y-balanceo-de-carga)